# Why is rails returning error after adding simple paperclip field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Here it goes
in the model

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "250" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

in the _comment.html.erb

```
  <% if !comment.image.url(:medium)  == '/images/medium/missing.png' %>
<img src="<%= comment.image.url(:medium) %>">
  <% end %>
```

like I said, it returns the error only if I include image
Ps. I did migrate and restarted the server
Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

ERROR

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

and it highlights responds to format in the create action in comments controller

```
  def create

if params[:comment][:parent_id].present?
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment][:parent_id]).replies.build(comment_params)
  #@comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment_parent = Comment.find(params[:comment][:parent_id]).user
  @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:comment][:post_id])
  puts 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff'
  puts @post
  puts 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddd'
elsif params[:comment][:parent_id].blank?
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user # I ADDED THE @POST
  @comment.create_activity :create, owner: current_user, key: 'commenting', recipient: @comment.post.user
end


    @comment.save
    @comment.body.scan(/@(\w+)/).flatten.to_a.each do|username|
    @mentioned = User.find_by_username(username)
    if !@mentioned.blank?
      @comment.body = username
      @comment.save
      @comment_body = @comment.body
      @comment2 = @comment
      @comment2.create_activity :create, recipient: @mentioned, key: 'mentioning'
      puts @comment_body
      mentioned_id = @mentioned.id
      mentioned_username = @mentioned.username
      @comment.body.gsub!(username, '<a class="mentioned" href="/user/' + mentioned_username.to_s + '">@' + mentioned_username.to_s + '</a>')
      @comment.save
      puts @comment_body
    end  
  end
  if @comment.save
  respond_to do |format|
     #format.html
     format.js
end

end
```

end

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @mccalljt sorry about that, added the error

Comment: And what does your create method look like

Comment: @mccalljt added it, sorry again